# How to stop an animation from resetting when adding a subview in Swift.?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, addsubview

Im trying to make items spawn at the location of the cloud. So far I have the cloud animating on repeat just how i want it, but when I spawn an item the cloud animation resets from the beginning.

when adding a `subview`, What are my options?

[Here is a gif from the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9I3.gif)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    gemCloudImage.center.x = 100
    makeCloudFly()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
}

func makeCloudFly() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(6, delay: 1, options: [.Autoreverse, .Repeat], animations: {
        self.gemCloudImage.center.x = self.view.frame.width - 100
        }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let positionX: CGFloat = gemCloudImage.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame.midX
    let positionY: CGFloat = gemCloudImage.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame.midY
    print(positionX)
    print(positionY)

    let chair = UIImageView()
    chair.image = UIImage(named: "CHAIR1")
    chair.frame = CGRectMake(positionX, positionY, 50, 50)
    chair.frame = CGRect(x:positionX, y:positionY, width:50, height:50)
    self.view.addSubview(chair)

}
```

Comment: Whenever you add a subview this line re-position the cloud. `gemCloudImage.center.x = 100`

Answer (score 1):

Move the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLoad`. That should resolve your issue.

The method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time you add new subviews.

Comment: I placed the initial X position of the cloud into the animation function and moved it into viewDidLoad. Its now working pretty well !